# How can I combine Alamofire with AEXML or SWXMLHASH

Tags: ios, swift, xml-parsing, alamofire

I want to parse a XML from URL which is RSS of my blog with SWXMLHASH or AEXML libraries. I found a solution for this but when I tried the solution my app crashed. 
It is the encountered problem:`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)`

And there are my codes which are in viewDidLoad:

```
` Alamofire.request("http://myblog.com/feed").responseJSON { response in

        if let data = response.data {

        let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(data)
           let news = xml["rss"]["channel"]["item"][0]["title"].element?.text
           print(news!)
        }
        }
`
```

Is there any other solution for this? I don't want to use NSXMLParser, I want to use these kind of libraries or If it is exist any up-to-date library, I can use.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I assume it is crashing at `print(news!)`. `news` must be nil, so your XML must not have anything at that path.

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/O1GwC) There is the main structure of my XML. I have began thinking, may I do a mistake.. Thank you for your comment Tristan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`Alamofire.request("http://myblog.com/feed").response`

not `Alamofire.request("http://myblog.com/feed").responseJSON`

I used AEXML.. try this

```
Alamofire.request("http://myblog.com/feed").response { res in

        guard let xml = res.data else {
            return
        }

        var options = AEXMLOptions()
        options.parserSettings.shouldProcessNamespaces = false
        options.parserSettings.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false
        options.parserSettings.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false

        do {
            let xmlDoc = try AEXMLDocument(xml: xml, options: options)

            print(xmlDoc.root["channel"]["item"]["title"].value!)

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Value of type AEXMLDocument has no member NSXMLParserOptions() ... And I tried numerous chances such as AEXMLOptions.ParserSettings , AEXMLDocument().options etc. It always didn't work. I think usage of XMLParser options has changed. And I really thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry.. I was using older version of AEXML. I changed it to latest version.

Comment: And I think you have to change `responseJSON` to `response`. You are parsing xml.. not JSON.

Comment: I changed responseJSON to response, and with your code... And happy ending! It worked! Thank you !

Comment: No problem! :-)